# how to GET responses when data post to URL in nodejs as req.body.url

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I want to get data from the URL I have entered as req.body.url inside the body of postman collection tool
how do I get the response

I have a key as URL and the value as live URL see the below screenshot
[image]

```
const options = {
      url: req.body.url,
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
          'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
      }
  };
  
  request(options, function(err, res, body) {
      let json = JSON.parse(options);
      res.send(json);
      console.log(json);
  });
```

tried above code but it does reads the URL and does not provide the data as response

Comment: What's the implementation of `request`? If it's https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback then it doesn't look like you are using it right. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: you send the options object back, what do you expect to happen?...

Comment: Nice censoring if you link your github account in your so profile and have only one public raml repo  ;)

Comment: @imranshaik Is there a reason for the `POST` method and not a `GET` ? With post you get a error page back... with get your content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
    var request = require('request');


const options = {
      url: req.body.url,
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
          'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
      }
  };

    request(options, function (error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(response.body);
    });
```

Note that request is asynchronous

Comment: I was trying with POST method when I changed it to GET it works for me

Comment: Already upvoted but i got below msg
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Could you try now